# Radon Transform Line Detection

Tags: matlab, image-processing, line, transform

I'm trying to detect lines in a grayscale image. For that purpose, I'm using Radon transform in MATLAB. An example of my m-file is like below. I can detect multiple lines using this code. I also draw lines using shift and rotation properties for lines. However, I didn't understand how to get the start and end points of the detecting lines after getting *rho* and *theta* values.

It is easy for Hough transform since there is a function called *houghlines()* that returns the list of the lines for the given peaks. Is there any function that i can use for Radon transform similar to this function?

```
    % Radon transform line detection algorithm
    clear all; close all;

    % Determine the path of the input image
    str_inputimg = '3_lines.png' ;

    % Read input image 
    I = imread(str_inputimg) ;

    % If the input image is RGB or indexed color, convert it to grayscale 
    img_colortype = getfield(imfinfo(str_inputimg), 'ColorType') ;
    switch img_colortype
       case 'truecolor'
         I = rgb2gray(I) ;
       case 'indexedcolor'
         I = ind2gray(I) ;
    end

    figure;
    subplot(2,2,1) ;
    imshow(I) ;
    title('Original Image') ;

    % Convert image to black white 
    %BW = edge(I,'Sobel');
    BW=im2bw(I,0.25) ;
    subplot(2,2,2) ;
    imshow(BW); 
    title('BW Image') ;

    % Radon transform 
    % Angle projections  
    theta = [0:179]' ;
    [R, rho] = radon(BW, theta) ;
    subplot(2,2,3) ;
    imshow(R, [], 'XData', theta, 'YData', rho, 'InitialMagnification', 'fit');
    xlabel('\theta'), ylabel('\rho');
    axis on, axis normal, hold on;

    % Detect the peaks of transform output  
    % Threshold value for peak detection
    threshold_val = ceil(0.3*max(R(:))) ;
    % Maximum nof peaks to identify in the image
    max_nofpeaks = 5 ;
    max_indexes = find(R(:)>threshold_val) ;
    max_values = R(max_indexes) ;
    [sorted_max, temp_indexes] = sort(max_values, 'descend') ;
    sorted_indexes = max_indexes(temp_indexes) ;

    % Get the first highest peaks for the sorted array
    if (length(sorted_max) <= max_nofpeaks)
        peak_values = sorted_max(1:end) ; 
        peak_indexes = sorted_indexes(1:end) ;
    else
        peak_values = sorted_max(1:max_nofpeaks) ;
        peak_indexes = sorted_indexes(1:max_nofpeaks) ;
    end
    [y, x]  = ind2sub(size(R), peak_indexes ) ;
    peaks = [rho(y) theta(x)] ;
    plot(peaks(:,2), peaks(:,1), 's', 'color','white');
    title('Radon Transform & Peaks') ;

    % Detected lines on the image
    subplot(2,2,4), imshow(I), title('Detected lines'), hold on

    x_center = floor(size(I, 2)/2) ;
    y_center = floor(size(I, 1)/2) ;
    for p=1:length(peaks)

        x_1 = [-x_center, x_center] ;
        y_1 = [0, 0] ;

        % Shift at first
        x_1_shifted = x_1 ;
        y_1_shifted = [y_1(1)-peaks(p,1), y_1(2)-peaks(p,1)] ;

        % Rotate 
        peaks(p,2) = 90 - peaks(p,2) ;
        t=peaks(p,2)*pi/180;
        rotation_mat = [ cos(t) -sin(t) ; sin(t) cos(t) ] ;
        x_y_rotated = rotation_mat*[x_1_shifted; y_1_shifted] ;
        x_rotated = x_y_rotated(1,:) ;
        y_rotated = x_y_rotated(2,:) ;
        plot( x_rotated+x_center, y_rotated+y_center, 'b', 'linewidth', 2 );
   end
   hold off;
```

Comment: Please tell us you're not just asking for the conversion from $ \rho , \theta $ to Cartesian coordinates!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I think the OP is asking how to find the endpoints of line segments, for which rho and theta are insufficient.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85  so the Radon tool doesn't give you rho,theta for both ends of the line?  It's not a line if there's only one coordinate pair!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft No, it will not. The transform itself yields a 2-D array with rho along one dimension and theta along the other. The value of the transform at (rho,theta) is simply the projection of the image along that line, where the line extends over the extent of the image. The pair (rho,theta) is indeed sufficient to define a line.

Comment: A point defined in polar coordinates corresponds to a line in cartesian coordinates. The formulation is like that "rho = x*cos(theta) + y*sin(theta). So, it does not give you the start and end points of the line. It only defines a line in the image plane. 

In MATLAB, houghlines() function takes the image itself, previously defined peak points in Hough transform, rho and theta values. So, is there any idea how can i implement a function that finds the lines for Radon transform like houghlines()?

Comment: It's kind of a hack, but once you have (rho,theta) you could resample the image along that line and then look for the endpoints by looking for where values spike up.

Answer (score 1):

There's a suggestion at [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897564/radon-transformation) which might help.  Then there's a rather complicated-looking research paper ["Sharp endpoint estimates for the X-ray transform and the Radon
transform in finite fields"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.1215v2.pdf), which appears just to show certain bounds on estimation accuracy.

From skimming other papers, it appears that it's a nontrivial problem.  I suspect it may be simpler (if less accurate) to use some adaptation of a [Sobel-operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) to identify high gradient points along the discovered line, and claim those as endpoints.